# Write to specific line on file

Tags: php

I want to be able to write to a file and always write at that line.

```
1 Hello
2 How are you
3 Good
4 I see
5 Banana
6 End
```

Using a function:

```
function filewriter($filename, $line, $text,$append) {
}
```

So append = add without overwriting the line and that's optional as it will default to append

so append:

```
filewriter ("bob.txt", 2, "Bobishere", true) or filewriter ("bob.txt", 2, "Bobishere")
```

output:

```
1 Hello
2 Bobishere
3 How are you
4 Good
5 I see
6 Banana
7 End
```

but if they don't append it looks like this:
  filewriter ("bob.txt", 2, "Bobishere", false)

output:

```
1 Hello
2 Bobishere
3 Good
4 I see
5 Banana
6 End
```

I've only managed to figure out how to overwrite the file or add to the end of the document.

What the function looks like currently:

```
function filewriter($filename,$line,$text,$append){
  $current = file_get_contents($filename);
  if ($append)
   $current .= $line;
  else
   $current = $line;
  file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```

Comment: show us your code, and we can look for the error.

Comment: Done! Sorry, I just didn't think it was useful :x

Comment: why all the tags? there's only php here

Comment: I wasn't sure if the solution would be ajax based or how it would have to be solved

Comment: Read the file into an array of lines, replace the desired element, write the (whole) array back to the file, done.

Comment: when you figure out how to work with PHP, you can add the cherry on top after ;-)

Comment: @enhzflep so what happens if the file size exceeds server (or php allowed) memory?

Comment: @CrayonViolent - Well tears, _obviously_ - you already know that. I estimated that the OP wouldn't be working with much data and that this would suffice. It's also why it's a 1 line comment rather than an answer. The line-by-line approach seems to be a concept not yet considered, either.

Comment: You could hold the files as ,say, an `SQLite` databased keyed on 'line number'. It would then be easy to change any line and recreate the sequential file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite your function:

```
function filewriter($filename,$line,$text,$append){
    $current = file_get_contents($filename);

    //Get the lines:
    $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\n|\r/', trim($current));

    if ($append)
    {
         //We need to append:
         for ($i = count($lines); $i > $line; $i--)
         {
             //Replace all lines so we get an empty spot at the line we want
             $lines[$i] = $lines[i-1];
         }

         //Fill in the empty spot:
         $lines[$line] = $text;
    }
    else
         $lines[$line] = $text;

    //Write back to the file.
    file_put_contents($file, $lines);
}
```

**PSEUDOCODE**

The logics behind this system is:

We got a list:

```
[apple, crocodile, door, echo]
```

We want to insert `bee` at line 2. What we will first do, is move all elements AFTER line 2:

```
1: apple
2: crocodile
3: door
4: echo
5: echo //==> We moved 'echo' 1 spot backwards in the array
```

Next:

```
1: apple
2: crocodile
3: door
4: door //==> We moved 'door' 1 spot backwards in the array
5: echo
```

Then:

```
1: apple
2: crocodile //==> This is a useless spot now, so we can put "bee" here.
3: crocodile //==> We moved 'crocodile' 1 spot backwards in the array
4: door
5: echo
```

And then we put "bee" on the line we want:

```
1: apple
2: bee //==> TADA!
3: crocodile 
4: door
5: echo
```

**Warning: the arrays in PHP are zero-based, so the first line is line `0`. Keep this in mind while using the above function!**

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain to OP how he can't insert bytes to a file, only overwrite them, without rewriting the whole file itself, due to OS and FS limitations.